# Bootstrap form doesn't retrieve SolveMedia POST data

Tags: forms, post, captcha, bootstrap-modal

I have created a form in a Bootstrap modal for user account registration:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="registerForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="newUsername" class="control-label col-xs-3">Username</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newUsername" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="newPassword" class="control-label col-xs-3">Password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="newPassword" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="newPassword2" class="control-label col-xs-3">Password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="newPassword2" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="newEmail" class="control-label col-xs-3">E-mail</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="newEmail" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Ajax

```
$(document).on('submit', '#registerForm', function () {
        var username = $("#newUsername").val();
        var password = $("#newPassword").val();
        var email = $("#newEmail").val();

        $.post("registration.php", { new_user: username, new_psw: password, new_email: email}, function(data) {
                var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                if (result.error) {
                        if (result.err_code == 1) {
                                $('#newUsername').css({"border": "2px solid red", "box-shadow": "0 0 3px red"});
                        }
                        else if (result.err_code == 2) {
                                $('#newEmail').css({"border": "2px solid red", "box-shadow": "0 0 3px red"});
                        }
                }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

I want to integrate the SolveMedia captcha and i follow these steps to do it: https://portal.solvemedia.com/portal/help/pub/php/

So i added the following code before `</form>` tag:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Captcha code</label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <?php echo solvemedia_get_html("my_key"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML output of `<?php echo solvemedia_get_html("my_key"); ?>`

```
<textarea name="adcopy_challenge" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="adcopy_response" value="manual_challenge"/>
```

The problem is that the form processing file doesn't retrieve the SolveMedia POST fields:

```
$_POST["adcopy_challenge"]
$_POST["adcopy_response"]
```

that are in the [SolveMedia library file](https://portal.solvemedia.com/media/download/solvemedialib.php) (that i included in my PHP file).

So my form send all values except the SolveMedia POST values.
According to the help section (https://solvemedia.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203660514-Always-Receiving-incorrect-solution-) i have to be sure that the form includes a POST method. Could the missing `method="POST"` in the Bootstrap form be the problem?

Comment: are you submitting the form with Ajax or method="post" ?

Comment: i'm submitting the form with Ajax

Comment: then method="post" is not necessary, can you post Ajax code and the output of `<?php echo solvemedia_get_html("my_key"); ?>`

Comment: Here is the Ajax code: http://pastebin.com/9q0M3Y55
The output of `echo` is the captcha box in which the user have to type the code.

Comment: can you also create a pastebin of <?php echo solvemedia_get_html("my_key"); ?>, need to see the it's HTML output, the problem is with Ajax, it's not posting the SolveMedia POST fields:

Comment: Do you mean this http://pastebin.com/427iLsBr ?

Comment: yeah, Answer posted, try and lemme know if it resolves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the Ajax code to submit the form

```
$(document).on('submit', '#registerForm', function () {
        var username = $("#newUsername").val();
        var password = $("#newPassword").val();
        var email = $("#newEmail").val();

        $.post("registration.php", { new_user: username, new_psw: password, new_email: email}, function(data) {
                var result = $.parseJSON(data);
                if (result.error) {
                        if (result.err_code == 1) {
                                $('#newUsername').css({"border": "2px solid red", "box-shadow": "0 0 3px red"});
                        }
                        else if (result.err_code == 2) {
                                $('#newEmail').css({"border": "2px solid red", "box-shadow": "0 0 3px red"});
                        }
                }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

If you look closer, you have created 3 `var` each for `username`, `password` and `email` but there are no `var` for `SolveMedia POST fields` you need to create `SolveMedia POST fields` like

```
var username = $("#newUsername").val();
var password = $("#newPassword").val();
var email = $("#newEmail").val();
var challenge  = $("[name='adcopy_challenge']").val();
var response  = $("[name='adcopy_response']").val();
```

once you will create `SolveMedia POST fields var` post it's values with Ajax here along with other input values

```
$.post("registration.php", { new_user: username, new_psw: password, new_email: email, challenge: adcopychallenge, response: adcopyresponse }
```

and on PHP side fetch values of `SolveMedia POST fields`

```
$_POST["adcopychallenge"]
$_POST["adcopyresponse"]
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! I just had to invert the end of post line, i mean i replaced this `challenge: adcopychallenge, response: adcopyresponse` with this `adcopy_challenge: challenge, adcopy_response: response`